# how do you know which functions in R are flagged for debugging?

Tags: r, debugging

I've been using `debug()` more often now, but sometimes I wonder which functions have been flagged for debugging.  I know that you can use `isdebugged()` to find out if a particular function is flagged.  But is there a way for R to list all the functions that are being debugged?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is convoluted, but it works:

```
 find.debugged.functions <- function(environments=search()) {
    r <- do.call("rbind", lapply(environments, function(environment.name) {
    return(do.call("rbind", lapply(ls(environment.name), function(x) {
          if(is.function(get(x))) {
             is.d <- try(isdebugged(get(x)))
             if(!(class(is.d)=="try-error")) {
                return(data.frame(function.name=x, debugged=is.d))
             } else { return(NULL) }
          }
       })))
     }))
     return(r)
 }
```

You can run it across all your environments like so:

```
find.debugged.functions()
```

Or just in your ".GlobalEnv" with this:

```
 > find.debugged.functions(1)
             function.name debugged
 1 find.debugged.functions    FALSE
 2                    test     TRUE
```

Here I created a test function which I am debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you wanted to get into something like writing a function to fire everything through isdebugged(), I don't think you can.

In debug.c, the function `do_debug` is what checks for the DEBUG flag being set on an object.  There are only three R functions which call the `do_debug` C call:  `debug`, `undebug` and `isdebugged`.

Answer (score 0):

which(sapply(lsf.str(), isdebugged))