# Listing functions with debug flag set in R

Tags: debugging, function, r

I am trying to find a global counterpart to `isdebugged()` in R.  My scenario is that I have functions that make calls to other functions, all of which I've written, and I am turning `debug()` on and off for different functions during my debugging.  However, I may lose track of which functions are set to be debugged.  When I forget and start a loop, I may get a lot more output (nuisance, but not terrible) or I may get no output when some is desired (bad).

My current approach is to use a function similar to the one below, and I can call it with `listDebugged(ls())` or list the items in a loaded library (examples below).  This could suffice, but it requires that I call it with the list of every function in the workspace or in the packages that are loaded.  I can wrap another function that obtains these.  It seems like there should be an easier way to just directly "ask" the debug function or to query some obscure part of the environment where it is stashing the list of functions with the debug flag set.

So, a two part question:

1. Is there a simpler call that exists to query the functions with the debug flag set?
2. If not, then is there any trickery that I've overlooked?  For instance, if a function in one package masks another, I suspect I may return a misleading result.

I realize that there is another method I could try and that is to wrap `debug` and `undebug` within functions that also maintain a hidden list of debugged function names.  I'm not yet convinced that's a safe thing to do.

UPDATE (8/5/11): I searched SO, and didn't find earlier questions.  However, SO's "related questions" list has shown that [an earlier question that is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614889/how-do-you-know-which-functions-in-r-are-flagged-for-debugging), though the function in the answer for that question is both more verbose and slower than the function offered by @cbeleites.  The older question also doesn't provide any code, while I did.  :)

The code:

```
listDebugged    <- function(items){
    isFunction  <- vector(length = length(items))
    isDebugged  <- vector(length = length(items))

    for(ix in seq_along(items)){
        isFunction[ix]  <- is.function(eval(parse(text = items[ix])))
    }

    for(ix in which(isFunction == 1)){
        isDebugged[ix]  <- isdebugged(eval(parse(text = items[ix])))
    }
    names(isDebugged)   <- items
    return(isDebugged)
}

# Example usage
listDebugged(ls())
library(MASS)
debug(write.matrix)
listDebugged(ls("package:MASS"))
```

Comment: In R base, there is no way to do that work other than wrapping `debug` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my throw at the listDebugged function:

```
ls.deb  <- function(items = search ()){
  .ls.deb <-  function (i){
    f <- ls (i)
    f <- mget (f, as.environment (i), mode = "function",

               ## return a function that is not debugged
               ifnotfound = list (function (x) function () NULL)
               )

    if (length (f) == 0)
      return (NULL)

    f <- f [sapply (f, isdebugged)]
    f <- names (f)

    ## now check whether the debugged function is masked by a not debugged one
    masked <- !sapply (f, function (f) isdebugged (get (f)))

    ## generate pretty output format:
    ## "package::function"  and "(package::function)" for masked debugged functions
    if (length (f) > 0) {
      if (grepl ('^package:', i)) {
        i <- gsub ('^package:', '', i)
        f <- paste (i, f, sep = "::")
      }

      f [masked] <- paste ("(", f [masked], ")", sep = "")

      f
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  }


  functions <- lapply (items, .ls.deb)
  unlist (functions)
}
```

- I chose a different name, as the output format are only the debugged functions (otherwise I easily get thousands of functions)
- the output has the form `package::function` (or rather `namespace::function` but packages will have namespaces pretty soon anyways).
- if the debugged function is masked, output is `"(package::function)"`
- the default is looking throught the whole search path

Comment: +1 This is good and seems to work.  I am stepping through it now, to learn what it is doing with `f`.  Clever.

Comment: Oversight on my part: stepping through with `debug()` is a better way to learn what it's doing.  Best use of `debug` yet.  :)

Comment: Thanks!  I learned several new functions and ideas from this function.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple one-liner using `lsf.str`:

```
which(sapply(lsf.str(), isdebugged))
```

You can change environments within the function, see `?lsf.str` for more arguments.

Comment: An example of this that checks all attached functions: `names(which(sapply(unlist(lapply(search(), function(x) lsf.str(pos=x))), isdebugged)))`

Comment: @sedsiv Please add the comment in your anwer. Yours does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since the original question, I've been looking more and more at [Mark Bravington's `debug` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/debug/index.html).  If using that package, then `check.for.traces()` is the appropriate command to list those functions that are being debugged via `mtrace`.

The debug package is worth a look if one is spending much time with the R debugger and various `trace` options.

Answer (score 1):

@cbeleites I like your answer, but it didn't work for me.  I got this to work but it is less functional than yours above (no recursive checks, no pretty print)

```
require(plyr)
debug.ls <- function(items = search()){
  .debug.ls <- function(package){
    f <- ls(package)
    active <- f[which(aaply(f, 1, function(x){
        tryCatch(isdebugged(x), error = function(e){FALSE}, finally=FALSE)
      }))]
    if(length(active)==0){
      return(NULL)
    }
    active
  }

  functions <- lapply (items, .debug.ls)
  unlist (functions)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I constantly get caught in the `browser` window frame because of failing to *undebug* functions. So I have created two functions and added them to my `.Rprofile`. The helper functions are pretty straight forward.

```
require(logging)

# Returns a vector of functions on which the debug flag is set
debuggedFuns <- function() {
  envs <- search()
  debug_vars <- sapply(envs, function(each_env) {
    funs <- names(Filter(is.function, sapply(ls(each_env), get, each_env)))
    debug_funs <- Filter(isdebugged, funs)
    debug_funs
  })
  return(as.vector(unlist(debug_vars)))
}

# Removes the debug flag from all the functions returned by `debuggedFuns`
unDebugAll <- function(verbose = TRUE) {
  toUnDebug <- debuggedFuns()
  if (length(toUnDebug) == 0) {
    if (verbose) loginfo('no Functions to `undebug`')
    return(invisible())
  } else {
    if (verbose) loginfo('undebugging [%s]', paste0(toUnDebug, collapse = ', '))
    for (each_fn in toUnDebug) {
      undebug(each_fn)
    }
    return(invisible())
  }
}
```

I have tested them out, and it works pretty well. Hope this helps!