# How do I turn off degugging of `[.data.frame` in R?

Tags: r

I am stuck in the debugger. I had an error in a function I ran using RStudio. I clicked the rerun with debugger and now every time I run it, it starts the debugger and I can't stop it. 
It tells me that the function being debugged is `[.data.frame` however if I try `undebug('[') or undebug('[.data.frame') I get

`Warning message:
In undebug(`[`) : argument is not being debugged`

I have restarted RStudio, but that does not help either. I have tried running some of the functions from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950602/listing-functions-with-debug-flag-set-in-r) to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using r studio?

Comment: @user10089632 - yes

Comment: @RichardTelford That does not appear to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then try this
"Debug" -> "On Error" menu and select "Message only"
click [here for more informations](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#stopping-when-an-error-occurs)